# How to return a JSON formatted array from an ajax request?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, json

I am building two interdependent drop-down lists, where the options of the second list (the 'sensor_list') depend on what option was chosen in the first list (the 'node_list'). To do that I attach a listener to the 'node_list' and when an option is selected I make an ajax request in order to load the data for the 'sensor_list'. All data, for both lists, is loaded from the same database.

In that ajax request I access the 'sensors' table on the database and I get the 'Sensor_ID' and the 'Sensor_name' of the sensors I need. What I want, now, is to pass this data back to the 'success' function of the request. Is this done automatically? Do I need to pass any arguments to the function?

Also, I need the returned data to be in JSON format, for later use. How is this possible?

Here is the PHP code:

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die('connection not made');
$db = mysql_select_db('name_of_db', $con) or die('db not selected');

$query = "SELECT SensorID,Variable FROM sensors WHERE SensorID IN (SELECT SensorID FROM nodesensors WHERE NodeID=node_selected)";
$result = mysql_query($query, $con) or die('query not made');

$options = json_encode($result);


?>
```

The 'node_selected' is the variable I pass with the request and it is the id of the node I selected in the first list.

The JavaScript is:

```
if (node_selected!=0 & node_selected!=null){
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "php/fetch_sensors.php",
                    data: node_selected,
                    success: function( options ){
                        ...//here I need the options to be in json format
                    }
                });
            }
```

'Options' is the data I want to be returned from the request and they are going to be the options for the 'sensor_list'.

Thanks a lot in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [mysql_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc) function for that

Try changing the PHP code to the following:

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die('connection not made');
$db = mysql_select_db('name_of_db', $con) or die('db not selected');

$query = "SELECT SensorID,Variable FROM sensors WHERE SensorID IN (SELECT SensorID FROM nodesensors WHERE NodeID=node_selected)";
$result = mysql_query($query, $con) or die('query not made');

$returnArray = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $returnArray[] = $row;
}

$options = json_encode($returnArray);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$options = json_encode($result);
```

To

```
echo json_encode($result);
```

And add `dataType:'json'` to your `ajax` call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "php/fetch_sensors.php",
    data: node_selected,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function( options ){
        ...//here I need the options to be in json format
    }
});
```

Comment: @Debflav I understand I was just saying you could edit the answer if it has a syntax error. the user will see your edit and be thankful for the edit :)

Comment: I did that but it didn't work. Also, I an alert('hello');  inside the success function but it never showed up. And when I tried to run the 'fetch_sensors.php' separately nothing but a blank page.

Comment: @dimitris012 I would suggest first to focus on the PHP code to make sure it really prints JSON. Try to set `error_reporting(E_ALL);`, maybe you have some hidden warnings.

Answer (score 0):

First off, [stop using `ext/mysql` if you can](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated).

You are not actually fetching the results from the query.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}
```

Then you actually have to emit the array to the response.

```
echo json_encode($rows);
```

jQuery is pretty smart about detecting JSON and should parse it automatically so you can use `options` as an object.  If it doesn't work automatically, you can do any of the following:

```
//php
header("Content-type: application/json")

//javascript
data: node_selected,
dataType: "json",

// *or*
success: function (options) {
    options = JSON.parse(options);
}
```

Finally since this request is an idempotent retrieval you should really be using `GET` instead of `POST` as the method.